# How to change the default size given to ApplicationBar in landscape mode in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

In landscape mode the `ApplicationBar` is placed on the side and it has a default size of `30px` more than it has when phone is in portrait mode.

1. How I can change this default size?
2. How I can place ApplicationBar on the bottom (not on the side) while phone is in
   landscape mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible - the Application bar is a system resource that is not available for the type of customization you are looking for.

If you are new to the platform, understand it's very unique. Don't try to port an android application 100% by adding the ApplicationBar at the bottom, and definitely don't use it for tabs.

Users expect the behavior of their device - I know when I rotate my phone, the bar buttons will move to the side.

Don't go mucking it up, it's bad UX to change the user's expectations of the platform.

Edit: removed code b/c ApplicationBar.Mode = Minimize doesn't work in landscape

Comment: If you try it you will see, that `Minimized` mode does not work in landscape

Comment: @willmel, regard the placing ApplicationBar to bottom I agree. But Minimize doesn't help! That's why I wrote that when ApplicationBar on the side it adds 30px more